# excel VBA break execution when there's no break key on keyboard

Tags: vba, excel, keyboard

I'm just noticing that on my laptop (Dell XPS 15z) there's no BREAK key (no dedicated number keypad). I'm running the debugger step-by-step and then when all seems fine, I just let it play out. However, it's running in an infinite loop and now I'm realizing there's no way to stop it without the break key!!!!

Is this a bad joke? I had to reboot the computer; is there a more graceful way??

Comment: `Is this a bad joke?` Unfortunately it looks like that. It doesn't have a BREAK key (http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tDGlM7WvfZg/TmPBV2ah6vI/AAAAAAAAAUY/x5_u0c9xgck/s1600/keyboardxps15z.jpg&imgrefurl=http://top10-stuffs.blogspot.com/2012/01/dell-xps-15z.html&h=821&w=1447&sz=204&tbnid=uxDOvn-Fvge1LM:&tbnh=69&tbnw=122&zoom=1&docid=y5gHW7u4o-HVmM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6fuFT8SbCsbJrAfryb3TBg&sqi=2&ved=0CGAQ9QEwBg&dur=365) Did you try `Esc` ?

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/12525/pause-break-key-on-modern-keyboards

Comment: NOTE TO READERS: there are a number of different solutions that are computer specific. If the top answers don't work, be sure to proceed down the list. In my case, the Dell Precision answer worked for my laptop.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

just press the escape key twice ;-)

Comment: I can confirm that this does NOT work on my Lenovo T431. And the item below does a cycle-between-apps.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz, it may be beneficial to make sure you have nothing like this in any of your code - Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

Comment: hmm, I'm not really sure what to tell you then. You may be able to get away with using the onscreen keyboard. See this article - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/type-without-keyboard#type-without-keyboard=windows-7

Comment: @BenStrombeck, on-screen keyboard did it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I have a Dell Precision without a **Pause/Break** key but there is a replacement for that: **Fn + B**, so:
 - <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> == <kbd>Pause</kbd> (pause execution);
 - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> == <kbd>Break</kbd> (break execution);
 - <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> == <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd> (open System properties).

You can execute the command:

```
dir /s C:\
```

and test the Pause and Break combination keys while dir lists all files in drive C.

[reference](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/keyboard-alternative-to-break.3759101/#post-14268707)

Comment: My Dell required ctrl-fn-b. None of the other solutions on this thread worked. Am very grateful for your answer!

Comment: Fn + B worked perfectly on my Lenovo T580!

Answer (score 10):

**Solution #1 (It works most of the time):** 
When some particular keys (<kbd>Pause</kbd>, <kbd>Break</kbd> or <kbd>ScrLk)</kbd> are missing on the keyboard and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> 2, 3 or multiple times doesn't stop the macro too.

*Step #01*: If your keyboard does not have a specific key, please do not worry and open the 'OnScreen Keyboard' from Windows Utilities by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

*Step #02*: Now, try any of the below option and of them will definitely work depending on your system architecture i.e. OS and Office version

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ScrLk</kbd>
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> (Press twice consecutively)

You will be put into break mode using the above key combinations as the macro suspends execution immediately finishing the current task. For eg. if it is pulling the data from the web then it will halt immediately before executing any next command but after pulling the data, following which one can press <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd> to continue the debugging.

---

When Solution #1 doesn't work or you need a permanent solution then try adding a new KEY to the Registry. (I am running Win 10 Creators Update on Dell 3530 Inspiron Laptop)

***Disclaimer***: Please only make changes to Windows Registry at your own risk and it is advisable only if you are windows administrator or have prior experience in the changing the key values in the registry.

You can also look for Solution #2 which use accessibility keyboard <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

**Solution #2:**
1) Click the START, then type REGEDIT into the search box. This will start the registry editor.

2) Explore the Registry, expanding each element 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
 -SYSTEM
   -Current Control Set
      - Control
           - Keyboard Layout

Click on the Scancode Map, and EDIT the key values to match that shown below.
i.e. to have values of  :  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,46,e0,44,00,00,00,00,00

Once Done you will need to reboot your laptop, but after that, you can use  as the pause/Break Key.

To understand it in detail and customize it as per your needs, please refer this link: [KeyBoard Scancodes](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html#ss1.4)

Comment: On screen keyboard and CTRL + Pause worked for me on an HP EliteBook. Thank you (3 years later)!

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> brings `OnScreen Keyboard`. At least, in Windows 11...

Answer (score 5):

Despite this being an old question, I have just encountered the same issue and discovered that `Ctrl+Scroll lock` works as a break.

"Scroll lock" can be accessed on my DELL Laptop via the blue function key "Fn" and the "F6" key which has a small blue lock symbol on it with an ⇳ symbol in it. At other computers it may look like ⤓ . So effectively I press Ctrl+Fn+F6.

Comment: Newer Dell Laptop - it's `F3` on mine, and has a lock icon. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have an HP laptop and this works when I want to break after a msgbox, hold fn+ctrl and click right shift key (has pause on it as well) then respond to msgbox and code will break.

Comment: Some one voted this down. I voted up, back to 0 again :-)
Breaking when on a MsgBox. I can confirm that this works on a HP ProBook. Took me ages to find this, completely missed the [pause] text on the shift key. Thanks Bob

Comment: This doesn't work on HP EliteBook...I had to quit DropBox, apparently it had a screenshot function on that key combo.

Answer (score 2):

On my Dell at least : ctrl + alt + esc     BEFORE your cursor starts looping itself

I got this info from aidangrogan on this website :

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19355018

So I don't claim to have found it myself. All credits to him (or her)

Answer (score 1):

Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> & hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> - Stopped my macro from running. I don't have a 'Break' key either on the keyboard of my HP Pavilion G7.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> works for Excel 365 (Office 365) on my Dell Latitude 5480 (no  <kbd>Break</kbd> key).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way round this, opened another instance of Excel and another spreadsheet, then opened the VBA editor from there and it showed as "running" so I could click the stop button

Comment: How exactly did you open another instance of Excel?  Windows won't let me do that, whenever I do it just brings the existing instance to the foreground.  I both right-clicked on Excel in the start menu and tried opening another workbook, and tried right-clicking in the task bar and clicking Excel.

Comment: @JayImerman,  To open another instance of Excel or any other application click (Left) Alt + (Left)Shift + application button. For example, I have Excel pinned to taskbar and to open a new instance I click Alt + Shift + Excel icon on taskbar. 
Want to add that you cannot copy paste the Excel way between two different instances of Excel.. if you copy from one instance and try to paste in another, you will not get all the Excel paste options. Similarly, you can not refer formula between files opened in two different instances of Excel. For such work, files should be open in the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread and saw the solution that has the most votes, but then realized my laptop has no <kbd>Pause</kbd>, <kbd>Break</kbd> or <kbd>ScrLk)</kbd> keys. I tried other proposed solutions, like 'OnScreen Keyboard' or alternative key combinations, but those didn't work either.

**Then it hit me: if it's a phantom break point associated with particular line(s) of code, why not just get rid of the line(s)?**

So that's what I did:

1. I cut the line(s) where execution was breaking.
2. Ran the macro again (it didn't break this time)
3. Pasted the line(s) again.

It worked for me, when no other key combination (onscreen or physical) worked. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers work for me.

I did how ever find [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b3cfa41d-a71a-4941-8531-fac20ab4bd5b/shortcut-to-stop-code-exectuion?forum=isvvba), it's not perfect since you need to keep <kbd>ALT</kbd> pressed and then a keys twice. On top of that it's depended on what language your Excel is set to.

In an English Excel you'd use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in German you need to use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I have a Japanese Layout keyboard. I neither have a scroll lock nor a break on my laptop-Lenovo E470.
A long press on the **Esc** key worked as a terminator for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because all of the above werent working for my application, I ended up writing a VBS script which I can run from the terminal.  Not elegant.  Probably not the first choice if one of the others work.  But, effective.

> `break.vbs`

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^%{BREAK}"
```