# Ctrl-C for quitting Python in Powershell now not working

Tags: python, powershell, exit

Python fails to quit when using Ctrl-C in Powershell/Command Prompt, and instead gives out a "KeyboardInterrupt" string.

Recently I've reinstalled Windows 10. Before the reinstall Ctrl-C quit python (3.5/2.7) fine, with no output.

Does anyone know why this has started happening? Whether it's just a simple setting?

The only difference I can think of is I'm now on python 3.6. Ctrl-D works in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, and Ctrl-C works fine in an activated anaconda python2 environment for quitting python.

Comment: I also faced this kind of problem with a running wsl image export. I eventually managed to kill the process by simply closing the Powershell window. While it may not solve everybody's "Ctrl-C in Powershell" problem, it might help some of the readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug that recently appeared in  Windows 10 Insider build 15002.

A work around is to change the Mapped Keys from Ctrl C to something like Ctrl K

If you are not familar how to do this, You can look up or at `stty -a`

You can run this command on each bash session that will map your Terminate to Ctrl + K

```
stty intr \^k
```

As a TEMP solution you could include this in your Bashrc so it is executed on each new session

This bug has been reported already on Github #1569

Comment: Thank you Dave. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 34):

I had this issue with Windows 10 Pro Build 18363 and Python 3.8.1. I was running some python scripts and was unable to stop some with `CTRL + C`, but `CTRL + BREAK` worked every time. [The Windows Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals) had this to say:

> The CTRL+C and CTRL+BREAK key combinations receive special handling by console processes. By default, when a console window has the keyboard focus, CTRL+C or CTRL+BREAK is treated as a signal (SIGINT or SIGBREAK) and not as keyboard input...
>
> CTRL+BREAK is always treated as a signal, but an application can change the default CTRL+C behavior in two ways that prevent the handler functions from being called:
>
> 1. The SetConsoleMode function can disable the ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT input mode for a console's input buffer, so CTRL+C is reported as keyboard input rather than as a signal.
> 2. When SetConsoleCtrlHandler is called with NULL and TRUE values for its parameters, the calling process ignores CTRL+C signals. Normal CTRL+C processing is restored by calling SetConsoleCtrlHandler with NULL and FALSE values. This attribute of ignoring or not ignoring CTRL+C signals is inherited by child processes, but it can be enabled or disabled by any process without affecting existing processes.

Thus, `CTRL + C` seems to be a SIGINT and its actions can be modified by the program you are running. It seems that Python on Windows has been coded in such a way that `CTRL + C` is being processed as keyboard input rather than the SIGINT we are expecting. Fortunately for me I have the `CTRL + BREAK` keys on my keyboard and this works every time.

For those of you who dont have `BREAK` on your keyboard, you can use the Windows On Screen virtual Keyboard.

1. Press `win key + r` to open the run application program.
2. Type `osk`and press ok
3. On the virtual keyboard, press `ctrl + ScrLk` and this should kill the program.

This [stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114447/excel-vba-break-execution-when-theres-no-break-key-on-keyboard) has some other methods you can try if `ctrl + ScrLk` doesnt work on the virtual keyboard.

Comment: In my case, I don’t have a break key in my laptop’s keyboard. So I use, Ctrl +Fn + B

Comment: Ctrl+ScrLK in the virtual keyboard worked!

Answer (score 14):

You can type

```
CTRL + Z,
```

then hit ENTER to exit python from powershell.

[Powershell Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgvQ7.png)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I found out that *right ctrl + c* does the trick in anaconda3 powershell - so no remapping necessary - I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: what is right ctrl?

Comment: This works. Right ctrl is the right control key on your keyboard. There is one on the left too.

Answer (score 2):

**That worked like magic**

If you have a laptop with Fn key, tap:

```
Ctrl + Fn + S
```

Source:
https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/break-key-alternative/td-p/3826467

Answer (score 1):

When you press Control C, a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception is thrown. If it isn't stopping the code, the best thing to do is to add a `try` statement into your code which catches `KeyboardInterrupt`

```
try:
    ....

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
```

The code is just off the top of my head so sorry if something is wrong.

EDIT: `Ctrl Break` or on some keyboards `Ctrl Pause` instantly stops python code apparently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it isn't about code stopping. It's just about quitting python. When I used to press Ctrl-C, python was quit normally without any output. Why has this now changed to give just an output of KeyboardInterrupt? I'm not brilliant at this stuff so apologies for anything stupid.

Comment: ctrl break is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting Esc button on the upper corner of the keyboard seems to work for me on Windows-7, inside Spyder with numpy running, for Python 3.+
It broke the infinite ...: on an erroneous syntax in the interactive script

Answer (score 0):

> When I used to press Ctrl-C, python was quit normally without any output.

I really don't remember when I can quit python with `Ctrl + C`. In my memory, `Ctrl + C` always give me `KeyboardInterrupt`.

---

I also counldn't find an answer explaining why `Ctrl + C` can't quit the python in shell. FYI, `Ctrl + D` and `Ctrl + \` can quit python for different reasons. See @Gilles's answer here. https://superuser.com/questions/169051/whats-the-difference-between-c-and-d-for-unix-mac-os-x-terminal

---

But I think how to handle `Ctrl + C` is merely a decision of the program. Yes, I think it totally depends on how the program would like to handle it. See the example I write below.

#### test.c

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void ctrlC_Handler(int sig){
    if(sig == SIGINT){
        printf("(:KeyboardInterrupt:)\n");
        printf(">>>");
        signal(SIGINT, ctrlC_Handler);
    }
}

static void welcome(){
    printf("Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)\n");
    printf("[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2\n");
    printf("Type \"help\", \"copyright\", \"credits\" or \"license\" for more information.\n");
    printf(">>>");
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main(){
    welcome();
    signal(SIGINT, ctrlC_Handler);

    for(;;){
        pause();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

compile it with `gcc test.c` and execute it `./a.out`. Try pressing `Ctrl + C`, you can see at least it mimics the behaviour(output) of the python program when you input `Ctrl + C`.

So, in my opinion, it's nothing special, but a human/programmer/author's decision on how to handle it.