# Macro stopping without breakpoint

Tags: vba, excel

I developed a macro that is running fine on my computer. But when I have the intended end user run the macro on their computer it keeps breaking at the same line of code even though there's no breakpoint. The relevant code is below:

```
Function MMFProcessor(Source_Folder_Str As String, Input_File_Name As String, Output_Sheet As Worksheet, NPU As String, Prods As String, sw As StatWin, _
    Processed_Members_Str As String, MbrRow_Dict() As String, FlgMeas() As String, Output_Sheet_Row As Long, Output_Mbr_Key_Col As String, Output_Name As String, _
    Optional Ambetter As Boolean = False) As Variant()
'
Dim Source_WB As Workbook
Set Source_WB = Workbooks.Open(Source_Folder_Str & "\" & Input_File_Name & ".xlsx", , True)
Dim Input_Mbr_Key_Col As String
Dim Input_Product_Col As String
Dim Input_SubMsr_Col As String
Dim ret As Boolean
ret = True
Dim Return_Array(4) As Variant
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim Source_Col_Nbr As Integer
Dim NumerCnt_Col As String
Dim SourceFile_Col_Cnt As Long
SourceFile_Col_Cnt = Count_Columns(Source_WB.Worksheets(1))
Dim Col_Str As String

'Set/Reset sw.Input_Sorted
sw.Input_Sorted = False '*****THIS IS THE LINE THAT CATCHES*********

If sw.Detailed_Log Then
    Call Update("Starting MMFProcessor. Inputs: Source_Folder_Str= " & Source_Folder_Str & "; Input_File_Name= '" & Input_File_Name & "'; Output_Sheet= '" & Output_Sheet.Name & _
        "'; Output_Sheet_Row= '" & Output_Sheet_Row & "'; Mbr_Key_Col= '" & Output_Mbr_Key_Col & "'; Output_Name= '" & Output_Name & "'", 0, sw)
End If
```

`Stat_Win` is a custom form that I put together to serve as a status window for the macro. The `Input_Sorted` variable does exist and is a Boolean. The other person running the macro has the same version of Excel, access rights to the folders being used, and is basically the same in any respect that I can think of.

Any help on non-obvious differences in system setup or any other reason the code might be catching that I haven't mentioned would be much appreciated.

Comment: How does the code break?  Does it open the VBA window and highlight the line in yellow?  Or do you see the continue/debug window?

Comment: It's possible the suggested fix worked. The code was not throwing the break prompt, simply stopping & highlighting the code as if you had already hit Debug. I went ahead & had my user use Ctrl+Break twice anyway and the code is running thus far, but that section of code is hit at least a dozen times so there's still time for things to go off the rails. If the execution finishes I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[It sounds like a ghostbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154699/excel-vba-app-stops-spontaneously-with-message-code-execution-has-been-halted). This is the solution for those:

1. Press "Debug" button in the popup.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause|Break</kbd> twice.
3. Hit the play button to continue.
4. Save the file after completion..