# Excel VBA "End Sub" Line Returns Error "Code execution..."

Tags: vba, excel, function

I'm working on an Add-In/Reference in excel VBA.  At the top of the Add-In I want to put a function which backs-up and saves the add-in.  I've coded the following, but keep getting the error "Code execution has been interrupted" on the "End Sub" line:

```
Sub SaveEditsToAddIn()

    DateAndTime = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd-hhmmss")

    Dim xlobj As Object
    Set xlobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    xlobj.CopyFile "c:\File.xlam", "c:\backup\File " & DateAndTime & ".xlam", True
    Set xlobj = Nothing

    ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: why is this a Function? if it's not returing anything ? it should be a regular `Sub`

Comment: I did change it to a sub, the error was the same.  The original reason it was a function was just because I was creating it in a function dictionary and out of habit created it as a function.

Comment: I changed it to reflect the correctness of your comment.

Comment: Your code "works on my machine". Does this link help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154699/excel-vba-app-stops-spontaneously-with-message-code-execution-has-been-halted

Comment: same here, you sure you have access to write to `"C:\"` ?

Comment: Actually, after reading the post here: https://optionexplicitvba.com/2013/08/22/the-two-worst-excel-errors-ever/ I rebooted the machine and everything is working fine.  It seems like it is some bug related to breakpoints and memory handling in excel(?).  Thanks for the tips and the links!