# Were there recent changes in VBA breakpoints and interactions with COM objects?

Tags: vba, debugging, breakpoints

In the past few months, debugging Excel VBA has become a nightmare for me.

It looks like, during step-by-step execution, a breakpoint is automatically set after every access to any member of a COM object defined in an external application.

For example, if I press F8 to execute a line that calls a function, and that function accesses hundreds of COM objects from an external application, the execution stops after every access, and I need to either press F8 hundreds of times, or set a breakpoint to the line after the original line and press F5. Pressing shift+F8 doesn't help, it will still stop to these phantom breakpoints.

I have test suites that I used to run by pressing F8 a handful of times, now I can only run them by setting one breakpoint per line and pressing F5 instead of F8.

I noticed this change in behavior (at least) a few months ago, but, since I don't work in VBA every day, I never bothered looking for help.

If this question does not really meet the Stackoverflow requirements, please let me know if there is a better place for it.

**EDIT**

Following Tim's suggestion in the comment, I tried to create an example that reproduces the problem. While working on the example I noticed that:

- The ghost breakpoints do not appear after *every* access to a COM object, they appear after *some* accesses and after *some* `DoEvents`
- The longer you work, and the likelier they are to appear, but I've seen them on the first try
- The more breakpoints you have, the the likelier they are to appear, but I've seen them without any breakpoints
- If you work long enough, they start appearing after *every* access and *every* `DoEvents`

The problem reproduces by creating a module with the following code, then:

- Click on `Sub Test()`
- Press `F8` twice
- Press `Shift+F8` -> the macro will run for a few seconds, and maybe, stop at a ghost breakpoint
- If the debugger doesn't stop at any ghost breakpoint, while the macro is still running, create a breakpoint by clicking on the gutter at the line with `Debug.Print "Done"` -> the macro will stop after a `DoEvents`
- When the debugger hits a ghost breakpoint, press `Ctrl+Shift+F8`, not `F5`
- If the problem does not reproduce, try again, keep adding and removing that breakpoint or other breakpoints. Sooner or later it will start stopping after `WordApp.Visible`, `CreateObject("Word.Application")` or other COM accesses.

```
Option Explicit

Dim WordApp As Object

Sub Test()
  Test2
End Sub

Sub Test2()
  Dim I As Integer
  For I = 1 To 10
    Debug.Print I
    CreateWordAppObject
    CloseWord
  Next I
  Debug.Print "Done"
End Sub

Sub CloseWord()
  Dim X, Doc As Object
  Debug.Print "Closing Word";
  For Each Doc In WordApp.Documents
    Debug.Print "Closing document"
    Doc.Close SaveChanges:=False
  Next Doc

  Debug.Print "Closing Word";
  WordApp.Quit

  On Error Resume Next
  Do
    Err.Clear
    X = WordApp.Visible
    If Err Then Exit Do

    Debug.Print ".";

    DoEvents
  Loop
  On Error GoTo 0
  Debug.Print

  DoEvents
End Sub

Sub CreateWordAppObject()
  Dim IsGlobalValid As Boolean, N As Integer, Doc As Object
  On Error Resume Next
  IsGlobalValid = WordApp.Visible
  If Err.Number Then Set WordApp = Nothing

  On Error Resume Next
  Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  On Error GoTo 0

  If WordApp Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Starting Word"
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  End If

  Set Doc = WordApp.Documents.Add
  For N = 1 To 10
    Doc.Content.Text = Doc.Content.Text & "Word " & N
  Next N

  DoEvents
End Sub
```

**EDIT2**

Here is a video that shows how the problem reproduces. Before starting recording I have created a new file and added a new module. Then the video shows that I pasted the code and stepped through the code. I only use the mouse to step through the code, so it's clearer than if I used keyboard shortcuts.

In this case it decided to stop at (maybe) all the COM accesses.
[image: ghost breakpoints]

Comment: Would be helpful to post a specific example which demonstrates the problem you're describing (ideally one we can run).

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't post any reproducible example because my real applications connect to CAD, CAM and other uncommon applications, and it would be impossible to reproduce. But I can try to reproduce the problem by using Word or other widely available COM server.... give me a few minutes, I will try....

Comment: Some other Office app was what I was thinking of...

Comment: It seems to be a stress related problem.
I restarted Excel, set a breakpoint where I had it earlier, ran to the breakpoint, pressed shift+F8 and now it worked as expected.
I removed the breakpoint, ran a test suite, set the same breakpoint, ran to the breakpoint, pressed shift+F8 and now it stopped down in the call stack at the (maybe) first access to a COM object. 
So it looks like the ghost breakpoints appear after running some other code, including that test suite.
The addin I'm working on has 60,000+ lines, 10+ references. It's late now, I will try to reproduce the problem tomorrow.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have followed your suggestion and I have added some code that seems to reliably reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce the problem here using your posted example.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for trying. I have edited the post and added a video that shows what happens to me. Debugging in these conditions is a nightmare. I can only set a breakpoint and press `F5` or `F8`, `shift+F8` and `ctrl+shift+F8` are unusable.

Comment: This might be useful?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154699/excel-vba-app-stops-spontaneously-with-message-code-execution-has-been-halted

Comment: @TimWilliams No. I know that problem it has always been there, while this problem is relatively new. I also added an answer that I think is better than any of the answers in that post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76970468/1899628

Comment: Finally noticed the "restart excel" comment.  After spending frustrating hours because code did not stop at breakpoints, I dealt with it using debug.print.  Not very effective.  Should have realized with MS products at the first sign of odd behavior',, reboot/restart/reload.  Just closing excel and restarting fixed the problem.  No need to export "basic" files, delete/reinsert code and so on.