# Excel Vba Find function randomly stops working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a toggle button on a worksheet that randomly works due to some .Find's in a module not finding the item. I get `Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error`.

This is the toggle button code:

```
Private Sub TbQueues_Click()

If Not DisableToggleClickEvent Then

    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
    Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting")
        
        If TbQueues.value = True Then
            TbQueues.BackColor = &HC0FFC0
            Ws1.Cells(1, 16).value = "Queues - Yes"
    
            FollowUpForm.Show
        
        Else
            TbQueues.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
            Ws1.Cells(1, 16).value = "Queues - No"
        End If
            
        SendKeys "{ESC}"

Else
    TbQueues.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
End If

Set Ws1 = Nothing
        
JobSearch.SearchData

End Sub
```

And this is the module code extract:

```
With Ws1.Range("A1", Ws1.Cells(1, L))

    Set FindResult = .Find("Active", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        ActiveStatus = FindResult.Column
    End If

    Set FindResult = .Find(Ws2.Range("K2").value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        DateTypeSel = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
    Set FindResult = .Find("Status", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        JobStatus = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
    Set FindResult = .Find("generated_job_id", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        JobNumber = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
    Set FindResult = .Find("payment_amount", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        PaymentAmount = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
    Set FindResult = .Find("total_invoice_amount", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        InvoiceAmount = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
    Set FindResult = .Find("category_uuid", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        JobCategory = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
    Set FindResult = .Find("queue_uuid", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        QueuesCol = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
End With
```

It is completely random and I have not been able to find any key factors that cause it. One time you click the toggle, either Ture or False, and the code runs perfect, the next time you click the toggle and all the .Find's in the module don't work returning 0. I ran it with the local window and all variables are either clear or set as they should be.

Comment: How is the `L` in `With Ws1.Range("A1", Ws1.Cells(1, L))` assigned a value? Side note: when using `Find`, always specify the `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` parameters. You're missing the `LookIn`.

Comment: `Match` would be faster than `Find` for this use case.

Comment: Is it possible you've reset set some other parameter in a separate call to `Find()`, and that's the issue?  Do you have hidden columns you're searching over for example?  For example hidden columns would not be found if "lookIn" is `xlValues`, but would be found using `xlFormulas`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Match` would be faster here, and you can push the checks out into a separate method:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim rw As Range
    
    Set rw = ActiveSheet.Rows(1) 'for example
    
    SetIfMatched rw, "Active", ActiveStatus
    SetIfMatched rw, Ws2.Range("K2").Value, DateTypeSel
    SetIfMatched rw, "Status", JobStatus
    SetIfMatched rw, "generated_job_id", JobNumber
    SetIfMatched rw, "payment_amount", PaymentAmount
    SetIfMatched rw, "total_invoice_amount", InvoiceAmount
    SetIfMatched rw, "category_uuid", JobCategory
    SetIfMatched rw, "queue_uuid", QueuesCol
    
End Sub

Sub SetIfMatched(rw As Range, header As String, ByRef variable)
    Dim m
    m = Application.Match(header, rw, variable)
    If Not IsError(m) Then variable = m
End Sub
```

Comment: This does work faster & better, thank you Tim. This has shown though that I have a issue someway else that I will have to track down. Now every time I run any code in VBA, it shuts down saying "Code execution has been interrupted". This means I have a serious bog down somewhere.

Comment: Maybe check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154699/excel-vba-app-stops-spontaneously-with-message-code-execution-has-been-halted